# Ubuntu server; Backup of server and MySql database, and Solr database

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, backup, solr

How is backup done on ubuntu servers?

I have a server (Ubuntu 9.10) which has apache2 installed, php5, mysql etc...

The website is a classifieds website where all classifieds are stored in mysql and Solr.

I need to backup this server with all information to be able to fully restore it if something goes wrong.

How should I start?
Is it an automated task, or will I do backups manually? (prefer manually)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no default backup-mechanism in ubuntu server.

First you have to decide if you want push-backups or pull-backups.

I pull my backups from my server with [rsnapshot](http://rsnapshot.org/). It works kind of like Apple's TimeMaschine. It transfers data using rsync and makes hardlinks for files that didn't change.

With rsnapshot you can run scripts on the remote server befor doing your backup. In one of those script i run mysqldump to backup my MySQL-Databases.

Backups should be an automated task, but be shure to do a test-restore once in a while to make shure everything works as expected.